# Global variable value not being updated in time

Tags: java, android, variables

So I've got a textview in android with an onclicklistener set using the xml

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usernameView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:onClick="userNameClicked"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

in the "userNameClicked" method I have

```
String usernamePointsDialog = "ITSSTILLNULL"; // this is the global variable that doesn't update until clicked a second time

    public void userNameClicked(View v) {

    global_position = postsView.getPositionForView(v);


    Log.i(TAG, "value" + global_position);

    int global_position2 = global_position - 1;

    String userObjectId2 = posts.getItem(global_position2).getUserString();

    Log.i(TAG, "value" + userObjectId2);

    // code that queries the database here
    {
    String userPointsFromDatabase = String.valueOf(userPoints2.getInt("userPoints"));
    // this is the code that returns the correct value but doesn't update the GV in    time

    Log.i(TAG, "value" + userPointsFromDatabase);

    usernamePointsDialog = userPointsFromDatabase;

    Log.i(TAG, "value" + userPointsFromDatabase);

    Log.i(TAG, "value1" + usernamePointsDialog);

    }

   }

});
        createDialog2().show();

   // this creates a dialog box that shows username (which is always the correct value, and the second value which always lags behind by one).
```

}

So my usernames that can be clicked are displayed in a listview, everything with the code works properly except the value of the global variable usernamePointsDialog lags behind by one, so if I click a username the correct username pops up but the value of the query to the database shows "ITSSTILLNULL" until it is clicked a second time, when it shows the correct value. All the Logs show that the correct values are being queried from the DB it's just that the global variable isn't being updated in time for the createdialog2 method to show (usernamepointsdialog) global variable as the correct value.

I haven't been able to use a final tag/ local variable for various reasons and am not sure what to do to fix this issue. Any help at all you can provide is much appreciated!

Comment: The code shows an `else` with no `if`, and is not indented properly. You might get a better response if you fix it. It sounds like a visibility problem. What happens if you mark the field volatile, or access it through synchronized getters and setters?

Comment: Will fix that right now, the reason it shows that else is I took out the database query code that included the if statement. Will try volatile/getters right after. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, after both setting the instance variable to volatile and wrapping it in getters/setters the exact same error occurs, where it takes two clicks to return the correct value and returns the initial string value of ITSSTILLNULL on the first click

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding something, but could it be that the variable isn't set until after the createdialog2() method is called, and therefore the correct value won't show until it's clicked a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, for some reason the createdialog2() method was being called before the code in the method ran. I simply moved the createdialog2 method call to right below the last log statement and it worked like a charm.